# Clip several rasters with multipolygon and save them as separate rasters using R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, clip

I'm trying to replicate this [example][1] but I'm not getting separate raster as an output. In my example, I have a multipolygon which has 2 polygons and 2 raster. My output I want to be 4 raster layers and the name of the raster I'd like to be 'id_band' where the 'id' part will come from the polygon's id column and the 'band' will come from the original raster (i.e. the final should be `14985_b6.tif`).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 library(raster)
polygon_areas <- raster::shapefile("test.shp")
plot(polygon_areas)
crop_save <-
  function(origin_folder,
           pattern,
           destination_folder,
           name_sub_folder,
           crop_areas,
           name_crop_areas) {
    file_list <- list.files(path = origin_folder, pattern)
    #Create folder
    dir.create(paste0(destination_folder, "/", name_sub_folder))
    how_many_areas <- nrow(crop_areas)
    #Create raster stack
    raster_stack <- stack()
    #File paths
    paths1 <- paste0(origin_folder, file_list)
    #Load rasters to stack
    for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
      raster_stack <- stack(raster_stack, raster(paths1[i]))
    }
    names_list <-  eval(parse(text = name_crop_areas))
    numbers <- 1:length(names_list)
    names_list <-
      paste0(as.character(numbers), "_polygon_", names_list)
    polyRR_list <- list()
    for (x in 1:nrow(crop_areas)) {
      pol1 <- assign(names_list[x], crop_areas[x, ])
      polyRR_list[[x]] <- pol1
    }
    for (j in 1:nlayers(raster_stack)) {
      dir.create(paste0(
        destination_folder,
        "/",
        name_sub_folder,
        "/",
        names(raster_stack)[j]
      ))
      for (k in 1:length(polyRR_list)) {
        a <- crop(raster_stack[[j]], polyRR_list[[k]])
        a <-
          mask(
            a,
            polyRR_list[[k]],
            filename = paste0(
              destination_folder,
              "/",
              name_sub_folder,
              "/",
              names(raster_stack)[j],
              "/",
              "RR",
              polyRR_list[[k]]$Id,
              ".tif"
            )
          )
      }
    }
  }

crop_save(
  origin_folder = "C:/Users/Geography/Desktop/a/" #Where your rasters are
  ,
  pattern = ".tif$"
  ,
  destination_folder = "C:/Users/Geography/Desktop/a/output/" #folder to save the rasters resulting from this operation
  ,
  name_sub_folder = "any_name" # Name of the sub-folder to be created inside the destination folder
  ,
  crop_areas = polygon_areas # The shapefile
  ,
  name_crop_areas = "polygon_areas$id" # The unique Id of the polygons in the shapefile
)
```

Also, the data I'm using:

```
list(new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(id = c(14985, 
23552), left = c(2665569.79702, 2670699.79702), top = c(1412205.45671, 
1407615.45671), right = c(2665839.79702, 2670969.79702), bottom = c(1411935.45671, 
1407345.45671), id_sample = c(1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 0:1), 
    polygons = list(new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", 
        labpt = c(80.3367355387047, 16.2821390031233), area = 6.1440311016086e-06, 
        hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(80.3354759967946, 
        80.3379981575006, 80.3379950690668, 80.3354729314431, 
        80.3354759967946, 16.2833585003835, 16.2833555285503, 
        16.2809195021546, 16.2809224739735, 16.2833585003835), .Dim = c(5L, 
        2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(80.3367355387047, 16.2821390031233
    ), ID = "0", area = 6.1440311016086e-06), new("Polygons", 
        Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(80.3523654989901, 
        16.2402853833502), area = 6.1434245505222e-06, hole = FALSE, 
            ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(80.3511062267076, 
            80.3536279907441, 80.353624759728, 80.3511030187666, 
            80.3511062267076, 16.2415050209594, 16.2415019107378, 
            16.2390657420334, 16.2390688522397, 16.2415050209594
            ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(80.3523654989901, 
        16.2402853833502), ID = "1", area = 6.1434245505222e-06)), 
    plotOrder = 1:2, bbox = structure(c(80.3354729314431, 16.2390657420334, 
    80.3536279907441, 16.2833585003835), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")), "b6.tif", 
    "b6.tif.aux.xml", "b6.tif.ovr", "b6.tif.vat.cpg", "b6.tif.vat.dbf", 
    "b6.tif.xml", "b7.tif", "b7.tif.aux.xml", "b7.tif.vat.cpg", 
    "b7.tif.vat.dbf")
```

I'm using R.4.1.1, RStudio 1.4.1717 and Windows10 x64
[1]: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/cliping-several-rasters-with-a-multi-polygon-shapefile/

Comment: One quick note; your pattern should be `"tif$"`. This will ensure that not all files with "tif" in the name are returned. It is not uncommon that there are associated files (eg., aux statistics file, rrd pyramids) that also have tif as part of the name (eg., "my.tif.aux") and if you try to read them as rasters your code will fail.

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, thanks for your answer, it did solved my initial problem. Although now I am having an other issue with the output. I updated my question

Comment: I've removed the rstudio tag and added the R tag. This isn't anything to do with Rstudio.

Comment: I apologize for that. I chose Rstudio tag because I'm using it, I don't write in R environment. Could you please explain in more detail why you remove Rstudio's tag so I won't make the same mistake in the future? Many thanks

Comment: Because R is the language you are writing, and RStudio is just one possible environment for writing R, and there's nothing specific to the RStudio environment in the problem. Tagging with R means anyone searching for the R tag will find this, and that's who you need. If your problem was with a menu or button or some other RStudio option instead of an R language problem, then you might want the RStudio tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the **answer** to the question above (i.e. using a multipolygon. In the *answer* section I posted an answer using *separate* polygons.

```
#Load shapefile
shape1 <- raster::shapefile("test.shp")
      
   crop_save <-
  function(origin_folder,
           pattern,
           destination_folder,
           name_sub_folder,
           crop_areas,
           name_crop_areas) {
    file_list <- list.files(path = origin_folder, pattern)
    
    #Create folder
    dir.create(paste0(destination_folder, "/", name_sub_folder))
    
    how_many_areas <- nrow(crop_areas)
    
    #Create raster stack
    raster_stack <- stack()
    
    #File paths
    paths1 <- paste0(origin_folder, file_list)
    
    #Load rasters to stack
    for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
      raster_stack <- stack(raster_stack, raster(paths1[i]))
    }
    
    names_list <-  eval(parse(text = name_crop_areas))
    numbers <- 1:length(names_list)
    names_list <-
      paste0(as.character(numbers), "_polygon_", names_list)
    
    polyRR_list <- list()
    
    for (x in 1:nrow(crop_areas)) {
      pol1 <- assign(names_list[x], crop_areas[x, ])
      polyRR_list[[x]] <- pol1
      
    }
    
    for (j in 1:nlayers(raster_stack)) {
      dir.create(paste0(
        destination_folder,
        "/",
        name_sub_folder,
        "/",
        names(raster_stack)[j]
      ))
      
      for (k in 1:length(polyRR_list)) {
        a <- crop(raster_stack[[j]], polyRR_list[[k]])
        a <-
          mask(
            a,
            polyRR_list[[k]],
            filename = paste0(
              destination_folder,
              "/",
              name_sub_folder,
              "/",
              names(raster_stack)[j],
              "/",
              polyRR_list[[k]]$id,
              ".tif"
            )
          )
        
      }
      
    }
    
    
  }

crop_save(
  origin_folder = "mydir/", #where the rasters originally are
  pattern = ".tif$",
  destination_folder = "mydir/", #where the output folder (below)will be created
  name_sub_folder = "cut_rasters", #this will greate a new folder, inside "a" inside whic will be two folders "b6" and "b7", with all the rasters of each polygon
  crop_areas = shape1, #your shapefile (which has to be loaded in R as aboce),
  name_crop_areas = "shape1$id")
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem but instead of a (single) multipolygon I used separate shapefiles. Below is the code:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

file_list <- list.files("mydir", pattern = "*shp", full.names = TRUE)
shapefile_list <- lapply(file_list, read_sf)
polygons <- do.call(rbind, shapefile_list)


crop_save <- function(origin_folder, pattern, destination_folder, name_sub_folder, crop_areas, name_crop_areas){
  file_list <- list.files(path = origin_folder, pattern)
  #Create folder
  dir.create(paste0(destination_folder,"/",name_sub_folder))
  how_many_areas <- nrow(crop_areas)
  #Create raster stack
  raster_stack <- stack() 
  #File paths
  paths1 <- paste0(origin_folder,file_list)
  #Load rasters to stack
  for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
    raster_stack <- stack(raster_stack, raster(paths1[i]))  
  }  
  names_list <-  eval(parse(text=name_crop_areas))
  numbers <- 1:length(names_list)
  names_list <- paste0(as.character(numbers),"_polygon_", names_list)
  polyRR_list <- list()
  for(x in 1: nrow(crop_areas)){
    pol1 <- assign(names_list[x],crop_areas[x,])
    polyRR_list[[x]] <- pol1
  }
  #dir.create(paste0(destination_folder,"/",name_sub_folder, "/", raster_folder))
  for(j in 1:nlayers(raster_stack)){
    for(k in 1:length(polyRR_list)){
      a<-crop(raster_stack[[j]], polyRR_list[[k]])
      a<-mask(a,polyRR_list[[k]], filename = paste0(destination_folder,"/",name_sub_folder, "/", polyRR_list[[k]]$id,"_",names(raster_stack)[j], ".tif"))
    }
  }
}


crop_save(origin_folder = "mydir/"
          , pattern = "tif$"
          , destination_folder = "mydir" 
          , name_sub_folder = "crop_Rasters"
          , crop_areas = polygons 
          , name_crop_areas = "polygons$id" 
)
```